# Getting more information out of error message when trying to do a parametrized query with ADODB in VBA

Tags: sql, vba, oracle, adodb

I am trying to use parametrized queries to insert values from excel into my oracle db using vba like in this [tutorial](https://evona.nl/simple-parameterized-queries-using-ado-in-vba/). It already works if I do it without parametrized queries. My code looks like this:

```
    Dim tmp As String
    Dim t As ListObject
    Dim cm As New ADODB.Command

    Set t = Worksheets("Sheet").ListObjects("Table")
    tmp = "insert into db_table1(name, color) values (@name, @color);"

    With cm
        .ActiveConnection = <working connection saved in a global variable>
        .CommandText = tmp
        .CommandType = adCmdText

        Set P1 = .CreateParameter("name", adVarChar, adParamInput, Len(t.DataBodyRange(1, 1)) + 1, t.DataBodyRange(1, 1))
        .Parameters.Append P1
        Set P2 = .CreateParameter("color", adVarChar, adParamInput, Len(t.DataBodyRange(1, 2)) + 1, t.DataBodyRange(1, 2))
        .Parameters.Append P2

        cm.Execute

End With
```

I get the error code

> Ora-00936: missing expression

Apparently, there is something wrong with the query the above code produces, I just can't figure out what exactly that is. Is there any way to get a more detailed error message or to see the query it is trying to execute?

Comment: In the SQL string try `?,?` instead of `@name, @color` and remove the trailing semicolon `;`.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit that worked, thanks a lot!. I assume I no longer need to add my parameters like Set P1 = .CreateParameter("name", …  now that I have replaced "name" in the query with "?" right ?.

Comment: A parameter name is not required - but it might be useful if you use the parameter several times.